# How to install nteract Data Explorer as an extension in JupyterLab?

Tags: npm, jupyter, jupyter-lab, nteract

How can I use [nteract Data Explorer](https://github.com/nteract/data-explorer) in JupyterLab?

From [this link](https://code.tubitv.com/building-a-model-driven-enterprise-3f37efa9db94), it seems like the `dx` can be installed in JupyterLab (image below), but I didn't find related docs:

[image]

Comment: The package was recently moved to its own repo, so the original link 404s. This is the updated home for that library. https://github.com/nteract/data-explorer#readme

Comment: I would really like to get nteract's data-explorer on jupyter lab, but the installation on their github page is not working for me, I can't find the neede path `applications/jupyter-extension`. @CameronYick can you help out with the installation process?

Comment: @NeStack, I've added a full explanation below. Feel free to open an issue on the Github repo directly if you run into further issues: https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab-data-explorer

Answer (score 3):

At the time of this writing, the installation process is different for jupyterlab than Jupyter notebook. This is because it's a different fundamentally different extension, with source code [here](https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab-data-explorer):

- Jupyter Notebook puts the explorer in the cell immediately below your code
- Jupyter Lab puts the explorer in a separate tab that can be opened by clicking the left menu pane.

To install it, run the following in your terminal:

```sh
jupyter labextension install @jupyterlab/dataregistry-extension
```

Further documentation about how to use the explorer is [here](https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab-data-explorer/blob/master/docs/usage.md), along with a sample [binder deployment](https://mybinder.org/v2/gh/jupyterlab/jupyterlab-data-explorer/4a47ff159818159450814b33b0b33f2221c223a5?urlpath=lab%2Ftree%2Fnotebooks%2Fdemo.ipynb) where you can try the explorer online.

Source: Thanks to Safia Abdalla in the nteract data-explorer slack channel for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

Adding to the answer by Cameron Yick: you can also get nteract's data-explorer to work for you by installing the dataregistry-extension (described by Cameron Yick) over the jupyter lab extension manager, completely graphically, without any code.

Regardless of how you install the extension, don't forget to add the line `pandas.set_option('display.html.table_schema', True)`, it turns the dataframes into json objects and only then you can use the graphical features of data-explorer. Eventually, you have to click on the small square icon on the left or right vertical bar in jupyter lab to get the data-explorer interface. See my instructions below:
[image]